# Html <a> tag stretching to entire page width

Tags: html, css

I just made a nice little button `<div>` wrapped in a link tag `<a>`. The problem is that the `a` tag stretches to the whole width of the page. I have no idea of how and why this happend since it haven't occoured for me before. I'll leave a codepen link and a snippet down here. Thanks in advance guys!
PS Note that the icons are just placeholders for the real ones! Don't judge them!

http://codepen.io/JohanSundman/pen/kkxbLg

```css
/*
.archive-link {
  width: 120px;/* Same as the button width *//*
  display: block;
}
*/

.archive-button {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.archive-button::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ae3535;
  /* Stacking context */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  /*Transition*/
  transition: width 250ms;
}

.archive-button:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.archive-button-down {
  background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/arrow-down-angle_318-52905.jpg');
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.archive-button-up {
  background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/ascendant-chevron-arrow-up_318-28667.jpg');
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.archive-button:hover {
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.swiftpeak.net/">
  <div class="archive-button archive-button-down"></div>
</a>


<br><br>

<a href="http://www.swiftpeak.net/">
  <div class="archive-button archive-button-up"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: @darham Well how do I make the div into a clickable link then?

Comment: The super easy option, is simply to give the link the `div`'s class, and fix any slight css changes

Comment: @JohanSundman There is nothing wrong with putting anything inside an anchor tag, please ignore the people who are saying there is. If you are unsure, you can check yourself here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<a>` tag is an inline element, and a `<div>` tag is a block level element.

Block level elements expand to the width of their parent elements. In this case, it's the `<div>` that's forcing your `<a>` to be full width. You could amend the `.archive-button` class  below with a `display: inline-block;` to alleviate the full-width behaviour you were seeing!

From [MDN][1]:

> ### Block-level vs. inline
>
> There are a couple of key differences between block-level elements and inline elements:
>
> #### Formatting
>
> By default, block-level elements begin on new lines, but inline elements can start anywhere in a line.
>
> #### Content model
>
> Generally, block-level elements may contain inline elements and other block-level elements. Inherent in this structural distinction is the idea that block elements create "larger" structures than inline elements.

**Edit**: Alternatively, you could also do away with the internal `<div>` element, and apply `.archive-button` to your `<a>` tag directly. Then you'd avoid all the comments about the illegality of a `<div>` in an `<a>` tag.

Comment: Thank you! Making the `<a>` tag into the actual button did the trick. However I would remove that snippet you have in your answer since it's not centered by the margin anymore. Here is a pen of the working example: http://codepen.io/JohanSundman/pen/vXdaBV